# Ionic ANDROID_HOME is set but still getting errors

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm new to Hybrid App Development, since a few days I have been fighting with how to build my Ionic App's APK file. I have tried `ionic cordova build --release android` as suggested [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html) but I see following errors:

```
    Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
    setting it manually.
    Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH'
    to include path to valid SDK directory.`
```

even then my `ANDROID_HOME` is set. Please note that I have tried reinstalling both Ionic and Android Studio but still getting the same error. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

What does happens when you do `echo $ANDROID_HOME` ? Does it correctly prints out the path to android home ?

If not :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
```

Also consider adding it to your path variable

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: When I do echo I get `/home/faizan/Android/Sdk` . Export is already done in`~/.bashrc`.